# Is there a way to get Google user reports for a domain quickly through python code? [google-admin-sdk]

Tags: google-admin-sdk

[google-admin-sdk]
I am able to extract reports for each user but this process is taking too much time, as my organization has 5500+ users, and each user is taking about 11seconds to fetch data for.
Yes, I know we can export data directly by going on console and exporting it, but I want this automated through code.
I am using python with Google's reports API.[Using Reports Api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMoNh.png)